# uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::SecureRandom

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having this strange error for the [devise_invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) extension:

```
uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::SecureRandom
```

But the strange thing is that I don't know how to load that module anyway, like if in my console I execute `ActiveSupport`, thats fine and responds with `true` but not that `SecureRandom` class, or `ActiveSupport::SecureRandom`, and like I know its part of ActiveRecord, it's in the docs here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/SecureRandom.html

How would you start troubleshooting an issue like this?

---

**More Details**

So it seems the class `SecureRandom` works as is, but not when called as part of ActiveSupport like `ActiveSupport::SecureRandom`, why would this be?

Comment: Which version of Rails are you on?

Comment: actually I'm on the edge version, so that might be just dumb on my part but whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this by switching to the `master` branch of Devise on my `3-1-stable` Rails application.

```
gem 'devise', :git => "git://github.com/plataformatec/devise"
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue with the `activeadmin` gem and solved it with a hack at the top of devise.rb

```
ActiveSupport::SecureRandom = SecureRandom
```

Source: http://coderwall.com/p/fttpra